# Base64 image coming across as array in JSON

Tags: php, json, image, base64

I am currently working on interfacing with a third party API that generates UPS shipments. One of the endpoints I am working with returns a base64 encoded image and a tracking number. The issue I have is that the base64 encoded image is coming across as a 27,000+ row array instead of a string.

I have been talking to their programmer, but he is a .net guy and can only tell me that the issue is related to me receiving the json with UTF-8 encoding. He states "there should be some kind of way to choose ASCIIEncoding when receiving the value back from the JSON package".

Here's the code I use for interacting with third party APIs via cURL:

```
/**
 * @param $url
 * @param $method
 * @param array $data
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function callApi($url, $method, $data = array())
{
    $curlObj = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json'
    ));
    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $data = json_encode($data);
                curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            }
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if (!empty($data))
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->_apiUser .":" . $this->_apiPassword);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curlObj);
    curl_close($curlObj);

    return $result;
}
```

Here's the code that specifically calls this method in order to setup a shipment:

```
 public function createShipment($quoteId) {
    $data = array('QuoteId' => $quoteId);

    return json_decode($this->callApi($this->_apiUrl . 'shipment/' . $quoteId . '?sessionID=' . $this->_sessionId, 'POST', $data));
}
```

Finally, a small subset of the json I am receiving back. I have chopped off all but a few of the rows in the image's array as not to spam the page, but to give a clear picture of what I am working with.

{
  "CarrierCode": 1,
  "CodAmount": 0,
  "IsSmartPickUp": false,
  "IsThermal": false,
  "LabelImage": [
    71,
    73,
    70,
    56,
    55,
    97,
    120,
    5,
    32,
    3,
    231,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    2,
    2,
    3,
    3,
    3,
    4,
    4,
    4,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    6,
    6,
    6,
    7,
    7,
    7,
    8,
    8,
    8,
    9,
    9,
    9,
    10,
    10,
    10,
    11,
    11,
    11,
    12,
    12,
    12,
    13,
    13,
    13,
    14,
    14,
    14
  ],
  "QuoteId": "b014d267-0850-49ce-b71d-28b82966b1c9",
  "ShipmentId": "b014d267-0850-49ce-b71d-28b82966b1c9",
  "TotalShipments": "1",
  "TrackingNumber": "1Z1A39W90393227795"
}

LabelImage is supposed to be a base64 image. How do I receive it in the correct format so that I can print the image out for our customer service folks?

Comment: It's rather unlikely that this will solve your problem, but you might convey to the .net developer that the point of base64 encoding was/is to transmit 8bit data over a 7bit/ASCII7 channel and every ASCII7 string is identical to its utf-8 representation as utf-8 was explicitly designed that way, ergo: regardless of whether the response encoding is ASCII or utf-8 the base64 string can be sent as a string. I'd consider that if not a design flaw of the api (implementation) then at least some laziness ;-)

Comment: I agree 100%. I don't know how many people they have using their API, but they need to take the time to fix this. Until then, I have to McGyver my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$result = createShipment($quoteId);
$base64_str = '';
foreach($result['LabelImage'] as $charCode) {
    $base64_str .= chr($charCode);
}
$image = base64_decode($base64_str);
```

Comment: By the way it's relay strange method of passing base64 data: a lot of data size overhead. That definitely should be fixed on server side.

Comment: I considered a solution like this one. My fear is that looping through 27,000+ rows in an array would be unnecessary overhead. +1 for having the same thought process I did.

Comment: I wrote some tests and in takes nearly `0.015 seconds` to decode image with 20k bytes size. It's 26k base64 characters (and elements in array) and 90k (!) json size, nearly as in your example. I think it's ok, because network latency is often longer : )

Comment: Although it's not the solution I would prefer to use, this one worked and I can now see the label image. Now, I just need to put a little pressure on them to clean their json up.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the .net developer is right and you have to inform the server that you accept/expect the repsonse data in ASCII encoding (or something similar).
Then there are still several possible ways to trigger that behaviour "in" the server application.

In descending order of likelyhood/correctness:

1. Add `Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1` to the array of request headers.
2. Change the Content-Type header to `Content-Type: application/json; charset=iso-8859-1` as when not instructed otherwise the server is supposed to answer with the encoding of the request* - but then you're only "allowed" to send iso-8859-1 data in the request as well.
3. Change the Accept header to `Accept: application/json;charset=iso-8859-1` - abusing the `parameter` field of the accept header; not good, but I've seen such implementations, but  ...try the other options first.

---

*) oops, or not.... "14.2 Accept-Charset" in rfc2616 says otherwise: `If no Accept-Charset header is present, the default is that any character set is acceptable.`

Comment: We tried this today. Sadly, it didn't fix the issue.